# CLion not correctly highlighting syntax while using remote host

Tags: c++, clion, remote-host

I am new to CLion and have been trying to make it work to my specifications. All is good except for the syntax highlighting; I do most if not all of my work using Remote Host and although the syntax highlights correctly locally, the syntax will not display the desired colors remotely. I have seen people say that this is due to advanced highlighting being disabled in Remote Host, but I was wondering if anyone has a remedy for this (reactivating advanced highlighting, etc)? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzSfh.png) shows the local, and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPZnw.png) shows the remote. Thanks so much in advance!

edit 11/2: pictures now reflect error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Note that this is not a coding question, rather a question pertaining to the interface of CLion.